# Perl's CGI::Session doesn't seem to find existing session (from PHP)

Tags: php, perl, session, cgi

I'm trying to instantiate a CGI::Session object from a session created in a separate PHP script; however, when I Dumper() the object, I see that the _CLAIMED_ID session id (which matches the PHP's session_id()) is different from the _SESS_ID (or whatever) stored in the _DATA member; more to the point, the _DATA member doesn't have *any* of the session variables that I registered in PHP.

HOWEVER! When I use PHP::Session (and passing the same sess id to its constructor), THIS object does indeed find the session variables in question.

Ideally, I want to use CGI::Session since it seems to be more robust and PHP::Session seems to be a lot more task-specific, so can someone suggest where I'm going wrong with CGI::Session? (Should I create a PHP::Session and then try to pass it to CGI::Session?)

Comment: CGI:Session implements sessions different than PHP's. The files may go into th esame directory as PHP's, but they're not compatible. Perl uses Storable or FreezeThaw for serialization, while PHP uses serialize() which is its own format.

Answer (score 5):

[PHP::Session](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PHP::Session) was designed to interoperate with sessions created in PHP.  [CGI::Session](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Session) was designed as a Perl-only solution.

CGI::Session does offer multiple back-end implementations, so in theory somebody could write driver, serializer, and id modules for CGI::Session that would be compatible with PHP sessions.  Nobody seems to have done that yet, though.